# API support for close actions

Tags: feature-request, api, write-access, closing

### Background

I would like to create an app for general Stack Overflow browsing to improve upon the UI. One of the things that I am targeting is the lack of certain options in the close dialog. I understand and agree with the reason many options aren't available, like extra sites in the "belongs somewhere else" category, and just more options under off-topic. It can get overwhelming for users, so the most useful ones are presented. However to more adept users the "other" box is often the only tool to explain what's wrong.

### Request

I would like an API method to close posts. Preferably it would be generic and allow me to do everything the normal close dialog does. That is to say, get a list of the default reasons (and subreasons), close based on any of those default reasons, or close with an "other" reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been implemented in API version 2.2.

To list the available close reasons, make a call to [`/questions/{id}/close/options`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/question-close-options). The result will list all valid close reasons, including pre-existing duplicate suggestions and off-topic comments.

You cannot assume that a close option will be available without calling this method to see if it actually is. **Always call this before actually attempting to VTC.**

Actually closing a question requires a call to [`/questions/{id}/flags/add`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question-flag)<sup>1</sup>, supplying the ID of the flag/vote you wish to cast.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, this is "flag" instead of "close". The documentation for close options explains this away by noting that

> Conceptually, closing is a subset of flagging.

Also, remember that users with between 15 and 2999 rep can flag to close, kicking a question into the queue for VTCers to look at.

---

## What `/questions/{id}/close/options` returns

Each flag/vote type in `(response).items`  has an `option_id` identifying it for later use. Pass this to `/questions/{id}/flags/add` to VTC with that reason. Each vote/flag also has a set of three booleans indicating additional data that may be required.

- ### `requires_question_id`

  True for close flag/vote types that reference another question (**duplicate**). When voting to close, supply the question's ID as `question_id`.
- ### `requires_site`

  True for close flag/vote types that reference another site (**off-topic -> migrate**). When voting to close, supply the site's domain or API identifier as `target_site`. (Note that this will only work if that target site is one of the preset migraton targets. Or, presumably, if you're a ♦.)
- ### `requires_comment`

  True for close flag/vote types that require a detailed explanation (**off-topic -> custom**). When voting to close, supply arbitrary text as `comment`.
- ### none of the above

  The call to close will be just fine given only the flag/vote's `option_id`. Applies to (**opinion-based**, **unclear**, **too broad**, **duplicate** (already chosen), **off-topic -> preset**).